# Django reference multiple image in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-template-filters

Hi I am letting the user upload multiple images per project but so far the images are not displayed. In `projects.html` all projects should be displayed and the title and the describtion work so far. But the main-image doesn´t show up. In `single-project` all images should be displayed.
What do I have to change in my models.py?
Thanks in forward

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    describtion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)

class ProjectImage(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    featured_images = models.FileField()
```

forms.py

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    featured_images = forms.ImageField(widget=ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple':True}))
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['title', 'describtion', 'featured_images']
```

views.py

```
def createProject(request):
    form = ProjectForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        images = request.FILES.getlist('image')
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save()
            for i in images:
                ProjectImage(project=project, image=i).save()

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'projects/project_form.html', context)

def projects(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {"projects":projects}
    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)

def project(request, pk):
    projectObj = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'projects/single-project.html', {'project':projectObj})
```

projects.html

```
 {% for project in projects %}
          <div class="column">
            <div class="card project">
              <a href="{% url 'project' project.id %}" class="project">
                <img class="project__thumbnail" src="{{project.featured_images.url}}" alt="project thumbnail" />
                <div class="card__body">
                  <h3 class="project__title">{{project.title}}</h3>
                  <h3 class="project__title">{{project.price}} €</h3>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
```

single-project.html

```
<h3 class="project__title">{{project.title}}</h3>
<h3 class="project__title">{{project.price}} €</h3>
<h3 class="singleProject__subtitle">Infos zum Produkt</h3>
{{project.describtion}}
```

project_form.html

```
            <form class="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}

                {% for field in form %}

                <div class="form__field">
                    <label for="formInput#text">{{field.label}}</label>
                    {{field}}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}

                <input class="btn btn--sub btn--lg  my-md" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the images of a project, you need to use the related manager in your templates:

**projects.html**

```html
{% for project in projects %}
          <div class="column">
            <div class="card project">
              <a href="{% url 'project' project.id %}" class="project">
                <img class="project__thumbnail" src="{{project.projectimage_set.all.0.featured_images.url}}" alt="project thumbnail" />
                <div class="card__body">
                  <h3 class="project__title">{{project.title}}</h3>
                  <h3 class="project__title">{{project.price}} €</h3>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I assumed that by "main-image" you mean the first image of the project.

**single-project.html**

```html
<h3 class="project__title">{{project.title}}</h3>
<h3 class="project__title">{{project.price}} €</h3>
<h3 class="singleProject__subtitle">Infos zum Produkt</h3>
{{project.describtion}}
{% for projectimage in project.projectimage_set.all %}
  <img src="{{projectimage.featured_images.url}}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

To avoid the N+1 query problem, you can also change the query in your view:

**views.py**

```py
def projects(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all().prefetch_related('projectimage_set')
    context = {"projects":projects}
    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html', context)
```